# Azure Functions HTTP endpoint parameter having space

Tags: javascript, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function with route as "project/{category}" which SQLs to my Cosmos DB. So my function.json has

"sqlQuery": "SELECT * from c where c.category = {category}"

Everything is fine when the HTTP endpoint parameter for category has no space like "http://.azurewebsites.net/api/project/rainbow" or "http://.azurewebsites.net/api/project/nospace". It is able to SQL category = rainbow or category = nospace.

But when I have an HTTP endpoint parameter like "http://.azurewebsites.net/api/project/rain%20bow" or "http://.azurewebsites.net/api/project/yes%20space". It does not show anything.

How do I handle parameters to be used in my javascript Azure Function? Replace %20 of context.bindingData.category to actual spaces " ", then run the sqlQuery.

Here is my code

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    if (context.bindingData.category) {
        context.res = {
            status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
            body: context.bindings.inputDocument,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        };
    }
    else {
        context.res = {
            status: 400,
            body: "Error"
        };
    }
};
```

Comment: I was able to get it to work by removing alpha in HTTP triggers route template. "project/{category:alpha}" to just "project/{category}". I was wondering what are the different types like alpha/int?

Answer (score 0):

`alpha` is a [Route Constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#route-constraints), it means `Matches uppercase or lowercase Latin alphabet characters (a-z, A-Z)`. It's an optional option.

Now there is a limitation with the HttpTrigger and it does not support request with extensions (see [this](http://there%20is%20a%20limitation%20with%20the%20HttpTrigger%20and%20it%20does%20not%20support%20request%20with%20extensions%20(see%20this%20for%20details).) for details).

As stated in the issue, you can use proxies to workaround this limitation, but you do need to remove the  `alpha` constraint from your route.